# is there any way of converting to a mesh from the Instance on Points node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image: my setup]

i have a geometry nodes setup. and i want to convert it to a mesh. because i can subtract the geo nodes setup from the thing in the picture. is there any way of making a mesh from the Instance on Points node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the *Realize Instances* node to create a "real" mesh.

Comment: thank you so much this helped a lot!